# How to delete div on key press?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to delete a div in HTML that occured when I clicked this `div` and then push key `Delete`, I use jQuery script to do it, but it's not working.

```js
$('div').click(function () {
  if ($('html').keyup().keyCode == 46) {
    var id_div = $(this).attr('id');
    var element = document.getElementById(id_div);
    if (document.getElementById(id_div).className = "mystyle") {
      element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div4" class="mystyle"></div>
</div>

<div id="div2" class="mystyle">
</div>

<div id="div3">
  <div id="div5" class="mystyle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that the error because of your lib.. Have you put jquery lib in your project?

Comment: *clicked this div??* which div of those divs?? .. for example if you click on div with id `div5` you want to delete `div5` or `div3`

Comment: = in your if statement should be ==

Comment: Dear sir, I check more condition `classname` , read more clearly. I will check if div with class `mystyle`, i will delete it, the problem in here , I can not capture event keyup with `key code = 46` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st: You need to include jquery

2nd: you need to append class to the div after click

3rd: you'll need document keyup event

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
  // div click
  $('div.mystyle').on('click',function(){
    // delete previous ToDelete classes from the divs
    $('div.mystyle').not($(this)).removeClass('ToDelete');
    // append new class `ToDelete` to the div
    $(this).addClass('ToDelete');
  });
  
  // document keyup
  $(document).on('keyup',function(e){
    // if key is Delete
    if(e.which == 46){
      // remove the same div you clicked on
      $('div.ToDelete').remove();
      
      // to remove the parent
      //$('div.ToDelete').parent().remove();
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.mystyle{
  height : 100px;
  border : 3px solid #000;
  margin : 20px;
}
.mystyle.ToDelete{
  border : 3px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div4" class="mystyle"></div>
</div>

<div id="div2" class="mystyle">
</div>

<div id="div3">
  <div id="div5" class="mystyle"></div>
</div>
```

> **Note:** the above code will remove the same div you clicked on .. *(if
>   you click div with id `div5` it will delete the `div5`)* if you need
>   to delete the parent div you need to use 
>   `$('div.ToDelete').parent().remove();` instead of
>   `$('div.ToDelete').remove();`

Comment: I think this is not a good idea, because it adds classes `ToDelete` to all the divs that you click, then deletes them all. I want is to just delete the div, which i click, and capture event `keycode = 46`

Comment: @BrianCrist answer updated .. for this thing you'll need another document click event to remove the class